# Appendix with a colon causing problems in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, appendices, tocloft

I have added a colon to Appendix in the toc using the following command.

```
\apptocmd{\appendices}{\apptocmd{\thesection}{:}{}{}}{}{}
```

Due to this, in the list of figures section, I am getting something like the following

```
Figure B:.1
```

when it should have been just

```
Figure B.1
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG3BX.jpg) of my list of figures, showing images from appendices. I want the ":" removed from there, since the format looks funky.

[Here is my MWE but more like my whole document.](https://dpaste.de/EmYO)

Comment: Can you explain what's your intent?

Comment: I want the colons on the appendices as they appear in the table of contents, but the colon is appearing in the list of figures when the images in the appendices are referenced there.

Comment: Normally there are no colons in the for appendices. If you change the definition of `\thesection`, it's quite natural to get `:` everywhere where `\thesection` is used, i.e. in the output of `\listoffigures` too.

Comment: I have edited the question and added an image.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am very sorry, I will post right away!

Comment: @tilaprimera Sorry, but we don't need such a big document. Is your aim just to have "Appendix A: AVR Atmega 8L Features" with the colon after "B"?

Comment: In the list of figures, the figures in the appendices also show up and while showing up, they come up as shown in the image link, with the colon. I just wanted colon come up in the APPENDIX A, APPENDIX B....not in the list of figures Figure A: .2 like this.

Comment: @tilaprimera: In my point of view, `Appendix A:.1 looks bad anyway...

Comment: There is not Appendix A.1, there is only figure A: .1, is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'quick' solution could be, to store the definition of `\thesection` right after `\appendices` start, then use the old definition in the figure environment, since this is a group and append the `:` to the `\thesection. Since the figure environment is a group, the old definition will only be used for figure references/captions.

Basically the same has to be done for tables, but I omitted this here.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\title{\textbf{Laser Pointer Based Human-Computer-Interaction using Computer-Vision}}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=3.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\text{Figure} }
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\apptocmd{\appendices}{\let\LaTeXStandardTheSection\thesection%
\apptocmd{\figure}{\let\thesection\LaTeXStandardTheSection}{}{}
\apptocmd{\thesection}{:}{}{}}{}{}




\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{First section}
\begin{figure}
\caption{First}
\end{figure}



\begin{appendices}



\section{First appendix}

\begin{figure}
\caption{First of Appendix}
\end{figure}

\subsection{First appendix subsection}

\begin{figure}
\caption{First of Appendix subsection}
\end{figure}



\end{appendices}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used your way, It works neatly!

Comment: @tilaprimera: Thanks, but look for `A:.1 First appendix subsection`... The `A:.1` does not look nice -- it's a consequence of redefining the `\thesection`

Comment: I do not have a subsection under a section. This crazy university format is driving me nuts, I would prefer a toc without colons, life would be pretty simpler without the colons. Thanks again! I hope I do not have to put the colons! : )

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is that subsections are typeset like

> **A: Title**

you should use a different approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\colon@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname: }
\apptocmd{\appendices}{\let\@seccntformat\colon@seccntformat}{}{}
\makeatother

\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{A title}

some words

\begin{figure}[htp]
OK
\caption{A}
\end{figure}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Something as appendix}

\begin{figure}[htp]
OK
\caption{B}
\end{figure}

some text
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]